# Python dataclasses and sqlite3 adapters

Tags: python, sqlite, python-dataclasses, sqlite3-python

What is the cleanest way to commit data stored in instances of a dataclass contained in a list to SQLite with `sqlite3`'s `executemany`?

For example:

```py
@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str
    age: int

a = Person("Alice", 21)
b = Person("Bob", 22)
c = Person("Charlie", 23)

people = [a, b, c] 

# ...

cursor.executemany(f"INSERT INTO {table} ({headers}) ({placeholders})", people) # <-- fails, obviously
```

Is there a built-in mechanism that does the work for me (goes over each attribute of the dataclass), or an idiomatic way, or, if not, how do I implement an [adapter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#how-to-adapt-custom-python-types-to-sqlite-values) for this without explicitly listing the attributes one by one?

I could convert it to a list of tuples, that works out of the box, yet feels redundant.

Comment: Use [fields](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.fields) and [asdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.asdict) from the dataclasses module. For example: `headers = ','.join(f.name for f in fields(Person))`, `placeholders = ','.join(f':{f.name}' for f in fields(Person))` and `people = [asdict(d) for d in (a, b, c)]`. It should be simple enough to work up a generic function that performs the whole operation. (Apaptors aren't relevant here, since you aren't converting individual value types).

Comment: You might want to use an ORM (e.g., `sqlalchemy`) to define the mapping between an instance of `Person` (dataclass or no) and your database.

Comment: @ekhumoro "Adaptors aren't relevant here, since you aren't converting individual value types" - This is clearly the part I didn't understand.

Comment: @chepner I am aware of it, but it's an overkill for this particular use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `astuple()` function to convert the dataclass instances to tuples.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, astuple

headers = ','.join(f.name for f in fields(Person))
people = map(astuple, [a, b, c])
placeholders = ','.join(['?'] * len(headers))
table = 'persons'

cursor.executemany(f"INSERT INTO {table} ({headers}) ({placeholders})", people)
```